# Why $F' \cong A$ as $A$-module in Lemma $1.1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have found a proof here [http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~saurav/MA5101/course-pid.pdf](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/%7Esaurav/MA5101/course-pid.pdf) as follows

**Rank of a module:**

Let $S = A−0$ and let $M$ be a finitely generated module. Write $K = S^{−1}A$. Since $K$ is a field, $S^{−1}M$ is a $K$ vector space. The rank of $M$ is defined to be equal to the dimension of $S^{−1}M$ as a $K$ vector space.

**Lemma 1.1.**
A finitely generated rank $1$ torsion free module is free.

**Proof:**
Let $F$ be a rank $1$ torsion free module. This means, there is an isomorphism of $K$-modules $K \cong S^{−1}F$. Let the image of $1 \ $ be $ \ x_1/s \ $. Let the $A$-submodule of $F$
generated by $x_1$ be $F'$. This means, if $y \in F$ then for some $a' \in A$ nonzero, $a'y \in F'$.
Since $F$ is finitely generated there is $a \in A$ nonzero such that multiplication by $a$
gives a map $F \to F'$, which is injective because $F$ is torsion free.  Since $F' \cong A$ as
$A$-module, $F$ is isomorphic to an ideal of $A$, which is free.

**My question is-**  Why $F' \cong A$ as $A$-module in Lemma $1.1$ ?

Please explain the last sentence of the proof of the above lemma.

Comment: Note that $F'=Ax_1$. What's the obvious map between $A$ and $Ax_1$?

Comment: @ThomasShelby, the map is multiplication by $x_1$. which is isomorphic